# Asp.Net wizard Storing State

Tags: asp.net

I'm confuse about which method is best for storing data when we use wizard.
Is it best to use Session or Database?

Comment: Without context, this question is unanswerable. No one can tell you which is objectively "best" without information about your specific application and needs. This is like asking which is a better pet, a cat or a dog?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you need
if you need persistence even though IIS restarted, user can logout and login, then use database
if you need temporary storage only, choose session